# Blackberry10 cascades Labelfield on-click

Tags: onclick, label, blackberry-10

How to add on click for a Labelfield to push one qml file to another qml file ,here is the code

```
             Label {
             text: "Don't have an account?"
             horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
             textStyle.fontSizeValue: 6.0
             }
```

and also want to place the back button and pop the screen's  can anyone send some sample code,to solve this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the onTouch signal:

```
onTouch: {
            if (event.isUp()) {
               //undisplay focus
               buttonClicked();
            }
            if (event.isDown() || event.isMove()) {
                //display focus
            } else {
                //undisplay focus
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you considered it closed? Thx